# Swift Command Line Tool - Read multiple lines

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, command-line-tool

I know the `readLine()` method, but if copy paste a text with more than one lines, only the first line will be retrieved.

I would like to retrieve all the text that the user copy pastes.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Question for you to think about: how do you know when the user has stopped typing/pasting? (Can they continue adding lines after they've pasted something? What about pasting two different things each with multiple lines?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `readLine()` in a loop and exit the loop in a predefined way

```
var input: [String] = []

print("Enter text, finish by entering Q")
while let line = readLine(strippingNewline: true) {
    if line.lowercased() == "q" { break }
    input.append(line)
}

print(input)
```

Example

> Enter text, finish by entering Q
> a
> b
> c
> q
> ["a", "b", "c"]
> Program ended with exit code: 0

Comment: Thanks, my problem was that on MacOS you cannot paste too many lines, it has a limit